# How to remove coupon programmatically in salesrule_validator_process event

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add some custom condition based on `cart item's custom option` on coupon code.

For this I am using `salesrule_validator_process` event and also added code for `cart item's custom option` condition but how to remove coupon or not allow to apply when condition not matched?

Here is my code :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) 
{
    $info_buyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
    $buyRequest = unserialize($info_buyRequest->getValue());
    if($custom_condition)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;       // here I want to remove coupon or not allow to apply
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace below code and check :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) 
{
    $info_buyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
    $buyRequest = unserialize($info_buyRequest->getValue());
    if($custom_condition)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
       //To remove coupon

       $quote->setCouponCode('');
       $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    }
}
```

Let me know if not work.

Comment: my quote has discount because it is category wise not coupon code needed,how can i do thsat?